# Find a particular solution of the above differential equation of the form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

$ \  \ 4\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+5x=f(t) \ $ ,

Find a particular solution of the above differential equation of the form

$ x_p(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos \frac{n \pi}{p} t=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g(t,n) \ $

**Then find out  the function $ \ g(t,n) \ $ ?**

where $ \ f(t)=\begin{cases} 2 , \ \ 0 <t <  \pi \\ -2, \ \ \pi <t<2 \pi \end{cases}  \ $  and $ \ f(t+2 \pi)=f(t) \ $

Also given that when $ \ f(t) \ $ is extended to negative t-axis in a periodic manner, the resulting function is $ \ even \ $

**Answer:**

The given equation is

$ \  \ 4\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+5x=f(t) \ $

The corresponding homogeneous part is

$ 4\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+5x=0 \ $

The auxiliary equation is

$ 4m^2+5=0 \\ \Rightarrow m=\pm \frac{\sqrt 5}{2} \large i \ $

Thus the complementary function is

$ x(t)=A \cos (\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}t)+B \sin (\frac{\sqrt 5}{2} t) \ $ ,

where $ \ A , \ B \ $ are constants.

**Now I can not find out the particular integral and the required function**  $ \ g(t,n) \ $

Actually I can not understand how to answer the question and in what process to approach .

I need help to get out of this.

Comment: To solve this you will need Fourier series. because $f(t)$ is even, look for representation of $f(t)$ as an infinite sum of cosines.

Comment: Can you do little more toward the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to find the complementary solution, just do what the questions asks.

You want the particular solution to match the periodicity of $f$, so $p = 2\pi$ and

$$ x_p(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\cos\left(\frac{n}{2}t\right) $$

To find the $A_n$, just plug $x_p$ into the ODE to get
$$ 4{x_p}'' + 5x_p = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (5-n^2)A_n\cos\left(\frac{n}{2}t\right) = f(t) $$

You may recognize this as a Fourier representation of $f(t)$. Therefore

$$ (5-n^2)A_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t) \cos \left(\frac{n}{2}t \right) dt $$